# Xamarin OnCharacteristicChanged

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy, xamarin-studio

I'm using **BLE** for send and receive data.

I can write data into `BLE` but response is not coming on `"OnCharacteristicChanged"` I am getting response on `OnCharacteristicWrite` while writing into `bluetoothgatt WriteCharacteristic`.

Please help me out to fix it. or suggest me the best practice or sample code.
Thanks in advance.

here is my **code.**

```
onDiscovered service
{
  string ser = "0003CDD0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b0131";
                    string charId = "0003CDD2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b0131";
                    bluetoothGatt = gatt;
                    //bleMTU = bluetoothGatt.RequestMtu(400);
                    mService = bluetoothGatt.GetService(UUID.FromString(ser));
                    charbt = mService.GetCharacteristic(UUID.FromString(charId));
                    bluetoothGatt.SetCharacteristicNotification(charbt, true);
}

Void writetosocket
{
byte[] smallPacket = new byte[numberOfBytes]; 
 charbt.SetValue(smallPacket);
charbt.WriteType = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WriteTypeNoResponse;
 bool check = bluetoothGatt.WriteCharacteristic(charbt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing to subscribe to the ReadCharacteristic. Here is how I implemented that part in my custom GattCallback:

```
class GattCallback : BluetoothGattCallback
{
    public BluetoothGattCharacteristic ReadCharacteristic { get; set; }
    public BluetoothGattCharacteristic WriteCharacteristic { get; set; }

    public override void OnServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, GattStatus status)
    {
        var service = gatt.Services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Uuid.ToString().Equals("0003CDD0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b0131"));

        WriteCharacteristic = service.Characteristics[0]; //Find your WriteCharacteristic
        ReadCharacteristic = service.Characteristics[1]; //Find your ReadCharacteristic

        gatt.SetCharacteristicNotification(ReadCharacteristic, true);

        //Subscribe on ReadCharacteristic for communication
        var readCharacteristicDiscriptor = ReadCharacteristic.Descriptors[0];
        readCharacteristicDiscriptor.SetValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.EnableIndicationValue.ToArray());

        gatt.WriteDescriptor(readCharacteristicDiscriptor);
    }
}
```